# Does whistleblowing make me unemployable?

Tags: ethics, university

I am an undergraduate who is particpating in my university's scholarship program, where we are given financial aid in return for volunteer work such as cleaning the buildings and preparing big school events.

While cleaning a room I discovered certain material that indicated severe violations of ethics in multiple levels.

The moral thing to do is to report my findings but I am worried that this would hurt my prospects in the academic and professional ladder.

I am the only one that cleans the place where the damaging material was found so I would be easily tracked down if the involved professors wanted to get revenge.

Will institutions and corporates be unwilling to hire/accept/promote me when it becomes known that I am a whistleblower?

Comment: You may be able to report anonymously. Look into the procedures for the relevant regulatory committee.

Comment: @BryaKrause I think the worry is that even if they report anonymously, "I am the only one that cleans the place where the damaging material was found so I would be easily tracked down if the involved professors wanted to get revenge."

Comment: What country are you in?

Comment: What is the nature of the ethical violation?

Comment: I think in some countries, revenge by the involved professors would be prohibited. I don't know whether this is relevant to you or how it works in practice.

Comment: Too vague for making it an answer, but I wouldn't think it makes you unemployable. Some people who hired are just not interested, some may even like it, and then many may not know. But it is true that there is a risk that it may affect your chances in certain places where people are friends with the professor in question for example. It's hard to say how high the risk is though. It depends on what kind of person the professor is, how much influence they have, where you later apply etc. You may also meet people who do not like this professor and may rather like that you came up with this.

Comment: I wish I had an answer for you. I might venture one if I knew a lot more about the situation (information you should probably not provide). But do let us know here what happens ...

Comment: What is "financial aid in return for volunteer work" other than "work"?

Comment: @Ambicion Direct tuition assistance rather than wages

Comment: @Ambicion Tax evasion. Though possibly a legal variant of it.

Comment: "financial aid in return for volunteer work" sounds a bit like an attempt to evade the host country's minimum wage legislation, and maybe that's the violation of ethics we should concentrate on.

Answer (score 1):

I do definitely think that demonstrating strong integrity should be something valued in both academia and in industry. But being low-income myself, I understand a need for both caution and tact in being in vulnerable position. Along with considering anonymous methods of reporting and looking into the legal framework on potential professional retribution, I'd consider more immediately whether a) there is documentation that specifically links you to cleaning that room, b) if not, how much time could you wait before reporting for others to forget who you are/where you were that day, c) whether involved professors would even be able to access information that links you to the room, and d) whether the academic environment you are in actually enforces strong academic integrity. Use these considerations in how you approach resolving this, maybe even identify faculty with strong academic integrity and would likely support you (broaching the scenario with caution of course).

Honestly, you shouldn't have to deal with these additional considerations and jump through these hoops. You should be able to safely report when something like this happens. But academia is just like any other workplace, which means there will be some unprofessionals despite status. I wish you all the luck in doing the right thing.

Answer (score 1):

No.  Most employers want to hire people who like rules.  Rules protect employers from litigation and fines.  Many employers require employees to report certain kinds of misconduct.

If you make people with guns or polonium angry, that might make you risky to employ.

> we are given financial aid in return for volunteer work such as cleaning the buildings

Sounds like the ethical violation was wage theft.

Comment: The last sentence seems unnecessary, calling a work-study program wage theft seems a little extreme.

Comment: @cag51 US federal work study always pays at least minimum wage.  If it's "volunteer" it's not work study.

Comment: The quote says that this "volunteer" work was done in return for financial aid.

Comment: @cag51 That's not actually what it says.  It says it was "given" for "volunteer work" which is not how minimum wage laws work.  I prefer to believe the asker rather than apply my expectations to change their words.

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated. Even if you anonymously reported, it will be known later who reported. So, I don’t think being anonymous would help. However if you report carefully, you may not face consequences given that ethics violations reported are severe enough that university fire professor involved. If you report to more than one level of higher authorities (such as dean or even higher level than that but not just the immediate boss of your professor) with all evidences that you think are ethics violations, that will force them to take action as well as keep you anonymous until the professor is fired. Once professor is fired, it doesn’t hurt you because fired professor won’t be in the position to hurt you. If you report misconduct to only the immediate boss of the professor, that may become counterproductive as well depending upon how much influence and power (such as grants, relationships, tenure, and others) the professor has in the department.